# how to find the flutter crash reason in android studio

Tags: flutter

When I start debug my flutter(2.0.1) app in Android studio 4.2, the app start and crashed. there has no error log output, what should I do to find why the app crashed? this is the startup log(no error message):

```
This will generate a JSON format file containing all messages that 
need to be translated.
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           16.8s
```

I run the run command:

```
 /Users/dolphin/source/cruise-open/.dart_tool/flutter_build/b649952ecb0be9dfc3fd2e301c2ba3d8/kernel_snapshot.d package:Cruise/main.dart
               [+1901 ms] ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/video_player_platform_interface-2.2.0/lib/messages.dart:4:1: Error: A library can't opt out of null
safety by
               default, when using sound null safety.
               [   +1 ms] // @dart = 2.8
               [        ] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
               [  +35 ms] ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/wakelock_platform_interface-0.1.0+1/lib/messages.dart:4:1: Error: A library can't opt out of null
safety by
               default, when using sound null safety.
               [        ] // @dart = 2.8
               [        ] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
               [  +71 ms] Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies
               [        ] don't support null safety:
               [        ]  - package:shared_preferences
               [        ]  - package:timeago
               [        ]  - package:hive
               [        ]  - package:hive_flutter
```

but I already add null safety config:

[image]

Comment: It seems like you are running in release mode. Run using the run button next to list of devices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please run the app using the command

```
flutter run -v
```

This will give you complete verbose logging.

Comment: I found the error is some package did not support null safety, but I already add the null safety compatiable parameter @Manjun Vasudevan